# How to sort prerequisites in makefile when getting all files from directory?

Tags: makefile

I am new to using makefiles. When running "example" I want to send each file from the INSTANCEDIR directory to the function "func", so I am using $^. Like so:

```
example: $(INSTANCEDIR)/*
    $(call func, $^, main)
```

However, the files are not in sorted order. I would like to get the files processed in alphabetical order. How would I go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(sort)`:

```
example: $(INSTANCEDIR)/*
    $(call func, $(sort $^), main)
```